# Ingest data from local file system to Snowflake via Apache NiFi

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, apache-nifi, snowflake-schema

I am working on one prototype where I am trying to push data from the local file system to Snowflake using Apache NiFi. I am able to do so using DBCP connection pool, but I am not able to map the columns just like we do in Matillion and other ETL tools. Is there any way I can map columns i.e. source file columns with target Snowflake table columns?

Answer (score 0):

Update: After some research I was able to resolve the above scenario using JoltTransformJson.

Comment: Can you provide more detail?